# Default admin color scheme as "blue"

Tags: admin

I don't like the grey one and i'd rather not change each user. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see easy way to change default so far, `fresh` color scheme seems to be hardcoded in plenty of places.

If you just need to force some specific scheme for all users it can be done with this:

```
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color','change_admin_color');

function change_admin_color($result) {

    return 'classic';
}
```